# Retrive $message variables in javascript file

Tags: 7, javascript

I am using Drupal 7.

In the template file `page.tpl.php` there is a variable called `$message` which prints the messages like error, warning etc.

I want to access this variable in a JavaScript file. How can I do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your page.tpl.php file:

```
$my_settings = array(
  'message' => $message,
);

drupal_add_js(array('my_settings' => $my_settings), 'setting');
```

Then in your JavaScript file you can access `$message` variable like this:

```
var message = Drupal.settings.my_settings.message;
```

Reference: [The Drupal JavaScript API](https://drupal.org/node/304258)