# Passing Settings from page.tpl to Javascript: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: 7

I want to pass this to my js file :
in **page.tpl**

```
<?php
$my_settings = array(
    'message' => $message,
);

drupal_add_js(
    drupal_get_path('theme', 'sizin') .'/js/anim.js',
    array('my_settings' => $my_settings),

    'setting');
?>
```

in **anim.js**

```
var message = Drupal.settings.my_settings.message;
```

i got this error from chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
```

Any Help/Idea ?

and i've read this : [Retrive $message variables in javascript file](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59282/retrive-message-variables-in-javascript-file)

Answer (score 1):

You need two line to add your code. Before one line to add js data settings:

```
$my_settings = array(
  'message' => $message,
);

drupal_add_js(array('my_settings' => $my_settings), 'setting');
```

and one line function to add file js

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'sizin') .'/js/anim.js', 'file');
```

And better you don't write code in file tpl. You cand add js file, js  settings in hook_preprocess_page(). It's drupal standard and clean tpl file.